# Unable to import modules despite installng them

Tags: python, module, pip

The packages are installed in what I feel is the right path: `c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages`. However, I am still unable to import modules.

I checked the Lib and site-packages on Pycharm and I saw that site-packages is highlighted red and I feel it has something to do with that but I don't know how to fix this.

[image]

Comment: When in Python, e.g. with a Python shell, see what `import sys; print(sys.path)` shows, and if that directory is included.

Comment: it wasn't and I did append that path but that did not help me import anyway. Please check the image and help if understand why my site-packages are fonted red if you can?